# Adding text to rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am creating a URL shortener and in-order for this to work I will have to change my .htaccess file to change the URL from `website.com/?id=myidhere` to `website.com/myidhere`. I have sorted this task out for numerals but I have no clue how to perform it for letters.
This is my .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(index\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3?%4 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So it rewrites the numerals but when i enter text in the id of the url it shows a 404 error. Would someone be able to help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it solves your problem, but to support numbers and/or text your regexp must be `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^myidhere$ id=myidhere [NC,L]
```

Comment: It needs to be any letter in the alphabet in any combination if that makes sense. for example id=dkgiak12

Comment: @OliverK ok let me try for that

Answer (score 1):

try this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now you can access your webpage from

```
website.com/myidhere
```